# Accessing the dataLayer (JS variable) when scraping with python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to scrape a webpages. I want to access the dataLayer (a javascript variable) that is present on this [webpage](http://www.allocine.fr/video/player_gen_cmedia=19561982&cfilm=144185.html)? How can I retrieve it using python?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it from the source with the help of *re* and *json.loads* to find the correct *script tag* that contains the json:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from json import loads
url = "http://www.allocine.fr/video/player_gen_cmedia=19561982&cfilm=144185.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

script_text = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("var\s+dataLayer")).text.split("= ", 1)[1]

json_data = loads(script_text[:script_text.find(";")])
```

Running it you see we get what you want:

```
In [31]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [32]: import re    
In [33]: from json import loads    
In [34]: import requests

In [35]: url = "http://www.allocine.fr/video/player_gen_cmedia=19561982&cfilm=144185.html"

In [36]: soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

In [37]: script_text = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("var\s+dataLayer")).text.split("= ", 1)[1]

In [38]: json_data = loads(script_text[:script_text.find(";")])

In [39]: json_data
Out[39]: 
[{'actor': '403573,19358,22868,612492,418933,436500,46797,729453,66391,16893,211493,249636,18324,483703,1193,165792,231665,114167,139915,155111,258115,119842,610268,166263,597100,134791,520768,149470,734146,633703,684803,763372,673220,748361,178486,241328,517093,765381,693327,196630,758799,220756,550759,737383,263596,174710,118600,663153,463379,740361,702873,659451,779133,779134,779135,779136,779137,779138,779139,779140,779141,779142,779143,779144,779145,779146,779147,779241,779242,779243,779244',
  'director': '41198',
  'genre': '13025=action&13012=fantastique',
  'movie_distributors': 929,
  'movie_id': 144185,
  'movie_isshowtime': 1,
  'movie_label': 'suicide_squad',
  'nationality': '5002',
  'press_rating': 2,
  'releasedate': '2016-08-03',
  'site_route': 'moviepage_videos_trailer',
  'site_section': 'movie',
  'user_activity': 'videowatch',
  'user_rating': 3.4,
  'video_id': 19561982,
  'video_label': 'suicide_squad_bande_annonce_finale_vo',
  'video_type_id': 31003,
  'video_type_label': 'trailer'}]
```

You could also use a regex but in this case using *str.find* to get the end of the data is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The beautifulsoup is not a JavaScript emulator, so you can't execute JS and get the content of a var. But maybe this var is populated by an ajax request and if you send the same request with your python script you can get touch those data.

In the other hand, if this data is statically assigned, then you can get them using string processing and regular expression.

*Disclaimer: Sorry, for the general answer.*

Comment: The data the OP is trying to get is in the source